# using titleView in storyboard source code

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I want to have a titleView in my navigationItem so that I get something like this at the top of the screen.

[image: Desired nav bar in UI]

I have found how to do this in code, like

```
navigationItem.titleView = MyCustomUiView
```

but I want to do it in the source code of the storyboard.

I get the rightBarButtonItem to display fine, but when I try to add a titleView barButtonItem, the xml won't parse.

Here is what I am trying:

```
                   <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="ddL-ut-3b9">    
                    <barButtonItem key="titleView" style="plain" id="11600">
                        <view key="customView" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="11599">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="140" height="44"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace" white="0" alpha="0"/>                                                                
                            <subviews>
                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Disclaimer" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="11601">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="116" height="37"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                    <color key="textColor" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB" red="0.982638542758316" green="1" blue="0.96209174603214" alpha="1"/>                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace" white="0" alpha="0"/>                                    </label>
                            </subviews>
                        </view>
                    </barButtonItem>               
                   <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" title="Log Out" style="plain" id="o6O-LC-29z">
                        <color key="tintColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>
                        <connections>                                <action selector="btnLogOut:" destination="24s-67-KDm" id="8tF-zL-Lq7"/>
                        </connections>
                    </barButtonItem>
                </navigationItem>
```

What am I doing wrong?

This one displays fine when it is the only one

```
 <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem"
```

But when I add

```
 <barButtonItem key="titleView"
```

I get, Could not parse xml

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to edit the storyboard source XML as text, especially for something so elaborate. You can't possibly do it correctly. (For one thing, you'd need to insert all the necessary `id` attribute info: I notice you've failed to do that.) The way to edit a storyboard is in the graphical storyboard editor. If you're not seeing the storyboard graphically, control-click it in the project navigator and choose Open As -> Interface Builder.

You also say

> when I try to add a titleView barButtonItem

The `titleView` cannot be a UIBarButtonItem. It must be a UIView, and UIBarButtonItem is not a UIView. So to configure this in the storyboard, add the desired view (or view subclass) to the scene, and connect the `titleView` outlet from the navigation item to it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I have all that done now, except I don't know what to do to "connect the titleView outlet from the navigation item to " the UIView I have now added.   Hint please.

Comment: Added a screenshot of me doing it.

Comment: NOTE: I am working in Visual Studio for Mac on a Xamarin iOS app.
For some reason, the Designer was wrapping the UIView that I dragged to the navigationItem, in a barButtonItem, every time. - resulting in xml like that in my original post. See more details below.

Comment: Well like I told you in my answer that's not what you do. You drag the view into the _scene_, not into the nav bar, and now you can hook the outlet to it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  @matt's "titleView cannot be a UIBarButtonItem. It must be a UIView" helped me get it working, but it was not sufficient guidance.  [NOTE: I am working in Visual Studio for Mac on a Xamarin iOS app.]

For some reason, the Designer was wrapping the UIView that I dragged to the navigationItem, in a barButtonItem, every time. - resulting in xml like that in my original post.

So, I deleted the barButtonItem element, AND replaced this

```
<view key="customView"
```

with this

```
<view key="titleView"
```

Sorry if I didn't do it the right way.  If you must give me another -1 then I guess you must.

: - )